# bsxfun: Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

Any one knows where the error is? Many thanks!

```
beta=randn(50,1);
bsxfun(@(x1,x2) max([x1 x2 x1+x2]), beta, beta')
```

error message:

> Error using horzcat
>   Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
>   Error in @(x1,x2)max([x1,x2,x1+x2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got (using two `max` in `bsxfun`)

```
beta = randn(50,1); 
res = bsxfun(@(x,y) max( x, max(y, x+y) ), beta, beta');
```

Verifying using `repmat`

```
tmp = max( cat(3, repmat(beta,[1 50]), repmat(beta',[50 1]), ...
                  repmat(beta,[1 50])+ repmat(beta',[50 1]) ), [], 3);
isequal( tmp, res )
```

Comment: That's what I want to get. Why max( x, max(y, x+y) ) works but max( [x y x+y] ) not? What if I want to get the pairwise result matrix [f(x1,x2) f(x1,x3) ... f(x1,xN); f(x2,x1) f(x2,x2) ... f(x2,xN);...; f(xN,x1) f(xN,x2) ,..., f(xN,xN)] for any f?

Comment: @yliueagle I don't know why `max([x y x+y])` does not work. Believe me, I tried. I also tried some other variations like `max( cat( 3, x, y, x+y), [], 3 )` - to no avail.

Comment: @yliueagle as for an arbitrary function `f(x,y)` why don't you just try it with `bsxfun`? If you implement the function in an m-file you can put a break-point in the function and see how exactly `x` and `y` are constructed...

Comment: @yliueagle BTW, if this solution works for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the  gray "V" icon beside it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but the error is in the transposition of `beta` as third argument of `bsxfun`; it works like this:

```
beta=randn(50,1); 
bsxfun(@(x1,x2) max([x1 x2 x1+x2]), beta, beta)
```

The second and third argument of `bsxfun` needs to be of the same size to apply element-wise binary operations to it.

**Edit:** From the manual (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

> fun can also be a handle to any binary element-wise function not
>   listed above. A binary element-wise function of the form C = fun(A,B)
>   accepts arrays A and B of **arbitrary, but equal size** and returns output
>   of the same size. Each element in the output array C is the result of
>   an operation on the corresponding elements of A and B only.

**EDIT2**: Is this, what you want?

```
A = rand(1,50);
[x, y] = ndgrid(1:length(A), 1:length(A));
idc = [x(:) y(:)];
allMin = min([A(idc(:,1)) A(idc(:,2)) A(idc(:,1))+A(idc(:,2))]);
```

First, with the second and third code-line I generate all possible combinations of indices (all pairs `i`/`j`), e.g.: If `A` has 3 entries, `idc` would look like:

```
1 1
1 2 
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1 
3 2
3 3
```

and then I'm building up a vector containing the value `A(i)`, `A(j)` and `A(i)+A(j)` for each row of entries (`i`, `j`) and getting the `min` of it.

Comment: I have an array beta (ex: beta=randn(50,1)). I want to calculate min([beta(i) beta(j) beta(i)+beta(j)]) for all pairwise i & j, avoid using loop. Do you have some suggestions? Tks!

Comment: @bjoern - this is your profile photo? couldn't you find something more appropriate?

Comment: @Shai I would say it's most appropriate, considering the recent requests we've had to "make the code sexy" ;-)

Comment: Yes this is it - and as far as I can see it's 100% SFW

Comment: @bjoern I understand that your profile picture is 100% SFW. Nevertheless, as you can see some (a very minor part of the population) does find it "uncomfortable". Under these circumstances, would you please consider something more conservative?

Comment: @bjoern: Not exactly. I tried your code and only get a single value as result. In fact I want to get a matrix looks like [f(x1,x1) f(x1,x2) ... f(x1,xN); f(x2,x1) f(x2,x2) ... f(x2,xN);...; f(xN,x1) f(xN,x2) ... f(xN,xN)]. where f is some function over x1 & x2.

Comment: @user3046721 For that, use `bsxfun(f, repmat(beta,1,50), repmat(beta.',50,1))`

Comment: Oh okay I thought you want the minimum of ALL values. Okay then use the code from Luis Mendo :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Your idea is quite intuitive. But when I tried the following:  beta=rand(5,1); f=@(x, y) max(x, max(y, x + y))==[x, y, x + y]; bsxfun(f, repmat(beta,1,5), repmat(beta.',5,1)); %%function f tries to catch the index of maximum. But I get error again. What I expected is to pass each combination of beta(i) & beta(j) to evaluate f, and get the result matrix [ f( beta(i), beta(j) ) ]. But bsxfun seems disagree with my logic.

Comment: @yliueagle The result of `==` is a vector of 0 and 1 values, not a single value. The function `f` needs to return a single value, otherwise `bsxfun` wont' work

Comment: @yliueagle To get the index of the max: try `[~, ind] = max(cat(3, repmat(beta,1,5), repmat(beta.',5,1), repmat(beta,1,5)+repmat(beta.',5,1)), [], 3)`